# How do I repair this old door lock?

Tags: repair, lock

An old knob on my bedroom door fails to retract to its normal position. I opened the lock in an attempt a repair it and discovered two loose springs.

[image]

I suspect that the loose springs aided a third spring to lift the door knob back to its natural position. Because the two springs have become loose the third spring is not able to retract the knob on its own.

[image]

I don't know how to reattach the loose springs. Does any know have experience with this type of mechanism?

[image]

Comment: Are there two loose springs or one broken spring? One end of each spring is coiled flat, the other end of each spring has a sharp end sticking out...

Comment: Very astute observation. I had not thought of that, and it's possible. I suspect not because of the distance between the coils at the bottom end of each spring; it's shorter, and the coils are almost pressed together. If this were a single spring, at the breaking point, I would expect the coils to be further apart. What do you think?

Comment: @User58220 I see now that my assumption was wrong and you were right. For unknown reasons I assumed that if the spring had indeed broken, it would do so because of over extension, not compression. It appears it broke because of compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That spring is definitely broken. It sits in the square bracket and pushes against the lever above it.

Do you have another working handle that you can disassemble to compare to?

[image]

Comment: That was it, indeed. Thank you for the illustrating it.

Comment: Come to think of it, I feel rather stupid, and some what annoyed, that this fact had not become obvious to me when I was annotating the photos.

Comment: It must have been broken in manufacturing. I would expect to see wear from the spring rubbing but it looks like there is none.

Comment: Springs are made of hardened wire. Sometimes there is a small flaw in the extruded wire that ends up as a micro crack in the spring coil as the wire is hardened. Through continued usage and flexure the micro crack can spread and eventually lead to total fracture as in this case. It should be relatively easy to get a replacement spring. As a minimum you could save the broken pieces and then contact the door lockset manufacturer and get them to send you some sample replacement springs. My experience in similar cases is that they really like hearing about (continued)...

Comment: (continued from above) product component failures like this. I've sometimes had to be a bit aggressive to get past the first line customer service to get to someone technical at the company. Most recently I had the power level selector switch go bad in one of two quartz rod space heaters. I ended up talking to the engineer at the company that had qualified the switch in the original product design and he was more than anxious to send me two replacement switches for free as long as I sent him the broken component for failure analysis.